# How to find the shaded angle of a right angled isosceles triangle?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

Hey everyone,

Just another question. I’m trying to figure out how to find the shaded angle of an isoceles triangle. All I know is the ratios between the sides and of course the value of the angles (as you can see in the image).

Can anyone help with this question? Thank you very much!

Comment: Set $AB = BC = 1$ for simplicity. Can you see how to compute angle $BXC$?

Comment: Ohhh I think I see what I need to do now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may arbitrarily place $B$ at the origin, $A=(0,1)$ and $C=(1,0)$. Then $X=(0,1/2)$, $Y=(1/3,0)$, $\vec{AY}=(1/3,-1)$ and $\vec{CX}=(-1,1/2)$. The angle between $\vec{AY}$ and $\vec{CX}$ may be found through the dot product:
$$\cos\theta=\frac{(1/3,-1)\cdot(-1,1/2)}{\|(1/3,-1)\|\|(-1,1/2)\|}=\frac{-5/6}{\sqrt{10/9}\sqrt{5/4}}=\frac{-5}{\sqrt{50}}=-\frac1{\sqrt2}$$
Hence the required angle is $\cos^{-1}-\frac1{\sqrt2}=\frac{3\pi}4$.

Comment: I used another way but I tried this way and it works as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way using two helper lines:

[image]

We have

$$\gamma = \alpha + 90^{\circ} + \beta$$

Because of the given ratios we have

$$\tan \alpha = \frac 13 \text{ and } \tan \beta = \frac 12$$

Using the tangent-addition formula it follows

$$\tan (\alpha + \beta) = \frac{\frac 13 + \frac 12}{1-\frac 16} = 1$$

Hence,

$$\alpha+\beta = 45^{\circ} \Rightarrow \gamma = 135^{\circ}$$